# Impurity From A Dog

Tags: fiqh, taharah, dogs, self-purification

Is sand on witch a dog sits impure? if the sand gets on clothes or hands is it necessary to wash them.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. As to your inquiry: Why should the sand be impure?